# delete IE browser history through powershell

Tags: powershell

This command is not woking on remote machine:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName comname -ScriptBlock{
c:\windows\system32\RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1  }
```

I am trying to delete IE history on remote machine

Answer (score 0):

Set aside the cache delete cmdlet, your Invoke is missing parameters for .. invoking, if the target device is "secured".

You at least need the following:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName * -Credentials Get-Credentials -ScriptBlock {}
```

I would usually add the following, but you do not necessarily need the authentication parameter.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName * -Credentials Get-Credentials -Authentication Negotiate -Scriptblock {}
```

You can read more about the Authentication parameter [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.authenticationmechanism?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0).

Last but not least, leave the path out. I think

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 1
```

is sufficient to have the script do what you want it to do. I tried it locally with C:\Windows\system32.. and it did not work, while running it "directly", as posted above, worked.

Comment: Invoke-Command -ComputerName * -Credentials  Get-Credentials -ScriptBlock{
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1  }

by using this i am not able to delete IE history

Comment: Please post some error messages. Alternatively, try running the command locally to somehow enclose what the problem might be.

Comment: while i am running this command on remote machine ,it is not give any error message
 RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 1 i run this command in my local machine , i am able to delete IE history